# Make argument of your function a text string

Tags: r

An elementary R question.  I would like to know if there is any possible way to take the given argument of a function and make it a character string, i.e. use the name of the variable.  I am using `mtcars` dataset and pass `mtcars$mpg` into my function and like to use the name of the vector in labeling my graph.

If I am passing vectors of a data frame into my function, how do I use the name of the vector as a title in my graph.

```
eda1 <- function(x){

    par(mfrow = c(1,2), oma = c(0,0,2,0))
    boxplot(x, main = paste("Boxplot", x))
    qqnorm(x)
    qqline(x)
    mtext(text = paste("Test Outliers for", x), outer = TRUE)
    }
```

I am tyring to figure out what to use in the `boxplot` and `mtext` functions where I have `x` to get `"mtcars$mpg"` in my function .  Suppose I give the command `eda1(mtcars$mpg)` and obviously the entire vector `x` is being passed as text.
[image]

I tried the `quote` function as such `name <- quote(x)` but that just stores "x" in `name`.

```
eda1 <- function(x){
    name <- quote(x)
    par(mfrow = c(1,2), oma = c(0,0,2,0))
    boxplot(x, main = paste("Boxplot", name))
    qqnorm(x)
    qqline(x)
    mtext(text = paste("Test Outliers for", name), outer = TRUE)
    }
```

I would like to store "mtcars$mpg" in the `name` variable when I give the call `eda1(mtcars$mpg)`.

Thanks

Comment: `(function(x){deparse(substitute(x))})(mtcars$mpg)`

Comment: Try `name <- deparse(quote(mtcars$mpg))` or `name <- deparse(substitute(mtcars$mpg))`.

Comment: Thanks @ImadAli `name <- deparse(substitute(x))` within my function worked.